# Mapping ID's to Names and Removing Duplicates Algorithmic Development

Tags: python, algorithm, csv

I have a column in a CSV file that has names such that each cell in that column could be the same as a slightly misspelled cell.  For example, "Nike" could be the same as "Nike inc." could be the same as "Nike Inc".

**My Current Script**

I've already written a program in Python that removes prefixes and suffixes from
each cell if that value occurs more than 2 times in the column as prefixes or
suffixes. I then compared one row to the next after sorting alphabetically in 
this column.

**My Current Problem**

There are still many cells that are in reality duplicates of other cells, but they
are not indicated as such.  These examples are:
    a) Not exact matches (and not off just by capitalization)
    b) Not caught by comparing its stem (without prefix and without suffix) to 
    its alphabetical neighbor

**My current Questions**

1) Does anyone have experience mapping IDs to names from all over the world
(so accents, unicode and all that stuff is an issue here, too, although I managed
to solve most of these unicode issues)
and has good ideas for algorithm development that are not listed here?

2) In some of the cases where duplicates are not picked up, I know why I
know they are duplicates.  In one instance there is a period in the middle of a 
line that is not present in its non-period containing brother cell. Is one good 
strategy to simply to create an extra column and output cell values that I suspect
of being duplicates based on the few instances where I know why I know it?

3) How do I check myself? One way is to flag the maximum number of potential
duplicates and look over all of these manually. Unfortunately, the size of our 
dataset doesn't make that very pretty, nor very feasible...

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0):

Try to transliterate the names, to remove all the international symbols, then consider using a function like `soundex` or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance (e.g. http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Fuzzy) to calculate text similarity.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I just read a bit more and it looks like double metaphone will be the best place to begin. Is there a good function you know of to do the transliteration or is that just me doing a bunch of "if" statements since there aren't that many characters involved?

Comment: nvm, i think i'm going to use unicodedata or unidecode, just need to figure out which one I want...